# What is the best/simplest way to connect my Silverlight 5 web-app to a Windows Azure database?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, azure-storage, ria

I have a fairly simple project in progress where I create a very basic upload/download capable Silverlight 5 app to upload a user-selected file from their local machine to an Azure database. After reading up on the variety of ways to do this (WCF RIA services and others) I haven't been able to get a clear idea of how I would best implement this.

Some more information about my app would be that I envision it to be very simple, with the upload consisting of a file selection and subsequent tagging and uploading to the Azure database and the download portion consisting of a user searching for the file in a pivot-viewer like environment and then selecting and downloading the file they want. If it is relevant: the app will run in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

How would I best connect my Silverlight app to a database set up in Windows Azure? Links to tutorials or explanations would be greatly appreciated! I'm looking for possible examples with sample code of how a Silverlight app could be written to connect and upload/download a file as well as samples/examples of what I need to setup on the Azure side in order for the app to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use any tool which migrates your schema and connect to SQL azure database  with proper server name using SQL server 2012.